# Autocomplete padrão do browser não funciona em minha aplicação WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou utilizando o ***Google Chorme*** e ele está com a opção ***autocomplete*** habilitada, tanto que consigo armazenar um login para o ***Facebook***.

[image: Exemplo de autocomplete no Facebook]

Porém, em minha aplicação ***ASP.NET WebForms***, na tela de ***login*** eu **NÃO** consigo utilizar esse recurso.
Não apliquei nenhuma rotina para limpeza dessas informações.

**Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer com que o `autocomplete`, que é padrão do `browser`, funcionar em minha aplicação?**

Segue minha **MasterPage** e minha página de **Login**:

***MasterPage***:

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.Master.cs" Inherits="App.Web.PaginaMestra.Pagina" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ordem de Serviço</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/rots.js"></script>

    <!-[if lt IE 9]>
    <script>
        document.createElement('header');
        document.createElement('nav');
        document.createElement('section');
        document.createElement('article');
        document.createElement('aside');
        document.createElement('footer');
    </script>
    <![endif]->

    <!–[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: white url(App_Themes/Default/images/bkg-blu.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .clear {
            zoom: 1;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]–>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPHDefaultHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmDefault" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPHDefaultBody" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Minha página de** ***Login***:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/PaginaMestra/Default.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="App.Web.Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentLoginHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHDefaultHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            if (window.location != parent.location) {
                parent.location = "default.aspx";
            }
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ContentLoginBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHDefaultBody" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManagerLogin" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="left: 50%; margin: -150px 0 0 -200px; position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 400px">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" SkinID="Panel" runat="server">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" SkinID="PanelTitle" runat="server">Login</asp:Panel>
                    <table style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 10px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <table style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 0px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Usuário" AssociatedControlID="txtUsuario"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsuario" Width="200px" runat="server" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="on"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUsuario" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUsuario" ValidationGroup="Entrar"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Senha" AssociatedControlID="txtSenha"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSenha" TextMode="Password" Width="200px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtSenha_TextChanged" ValidationGroup="Entrar"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSenha" SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSenha" ValidationGroup="Entrar"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <br />
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEsqueceuSenha" runat="server" OnClick="btnEsqueceuSenha_Click">Esqueceu sua senha?</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
                                <img src="App_Themes/Default/images/acesso_admin.png" style="width: 80px;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbEntrar" SkinID="Entrar" runat="server" OnClick="lkbEntrar_Click" ValidationGroup="Entrar"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <br />
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Se precisarem de mais informações, é só pedir.

Comment: O autocomplete do navegador, usa o atributo `id` ou `name` para persistir os dados já informados, talvez o asp possa estar gerando esses valores sempre diferentes, assim o navegador considera esse um nvo campo, não mostrando o autocomplete

Comment: Não está mudando o nome e o id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não estou vendo, a princípio, utilidade para o `UpdatePanel`.
Teste sem ele. Deve funcionar, e então, reavalie o uso do `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: obrigado, funcionou! Então o update panel que faz isso. Provavelmente é no post efetuado pelo submit que o browser captura esses dados para armazenar. O `UpdatePanel` realmente não estava com uso necessário. Finalmente, estou pronto para dominar o mundo.

Comment: @José rs, provavelmente é no **POST** do **Submit** sim.

Comment: @user3628 você pode fazer ele via ajax também. muito mais simples.